# Signal-processing (morse code decoding) with Android application

Tags: android, signal-processing, audio-recording

I made test application in Delphi that beeps morse code using Windows API Beep function. Then made an application in Android that stores this morse code in WAV file. Now I want Android application to decode the morse code. Is there some tutorials for sound processing or can somebody post some simple code (think there's no simplicity here) for an example? Or maybe steps that I need to do to get it work?

I also downloaded the JTransforms and jfttw libraries but don't really know where to start.

Regards,
evilone

Comment: You could start by separating the task into deciding if the tone is present or not, and then decoding the timing to characters.  Though it could be argued that there should be some feedback from the second to the first if you want to track variable conditions.  Your test data right now will be very consistent so that will make it easier than in the real world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An FFT is overkill for this - you can just use a simple [Goertzel filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm) to isolate the morse code from background noise, then decode the output of this.

Comment: A Goertzel filter might work if you already know the frequency of the Morse code tones.

Comment: I'm assuming that, since he is creating the tones in the first place, he will know the frequency. ;-)

Comment: @Paul R Yep, that's correct. The frequency for WinAPI beep can be between 37 to 32767 Hz. I'm using 1206 Hz for '.' and 1200 Hz for '-'. But still cannot figure out where I need to start to decoding morse from this file. First step is read the file to byte array?

Comment: @evilone: that's not really Morse code then - the dots and dashes should have the same frequency - the duration of each is what carries information - dots are one unit in duration, dashes are three units in durations.

Comment: Ok, made them same frequency. I read about durations from wikipedia. Also theres 7 unit long pause between words and one unit long pause between dots and dashes. But what are the next steps?

Comment: @e-one : Steps might consist of: Learn how to read a WAV file into a (PCM) sample array in memory.  Learn what the samples mean (data types and sampling theory).  Learn what your beep waveforms might look like in the form of audio samples.  Figure out how to write some DSP code (Goertzel/IIR, FIR filter, DFT/FFT, etc.) to detect those waveforms in your data.  And etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think an older issues of QST magazine had an article on DSP for Morse/CW decoding several years back.  Might want to try and search their archives.

Basically, you need DSP code to determine whether or not a tone is present at any given point in time, and an estimate of the onset and off-time of each tone.  Then scale the duration of each tone and the gap times between the tones for the expected code speed, and compare against a table of timings for each Morse code letter to estimate the probability of each or any letter being present.

In the simplest case, you might have a dot-dash-space decision tree.  In severe noise and fading plus highly personalized fist/timing you might need some sophisticated statistical and/or adaptive audio pattern matching techniques for decent results.

Comment: Is this correct one http://www.arrl.org/files/file/Technology/tis/info/pdf/9402qex2.pdf ?

Comment: @evilone : There are probably several QST/QEX articles on this subject.  CCW seems to require a special sending technique.